# External JS in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to setup a custom chat
and it expects something like this:

```
<script>
  window.fcSettings = {
    token: "737838-363673273278-782828",
    host: "https://wchat.freshchat.com",
    externalId: "john.doe1987",     // user’s id unique to your system
    firstName: "John",              // user’s first name
    lastName: "Doe",                // user’s last name
    email: "john.doe@gmail.com",    // user’s email address
    phone: "8668323090",            // phone number without country code
    phoneCountryCode: "+1"          // phone’s country code
  };
</script>
<script src="https://wchat.freshchat.com/js/widget.js" async></script>
```

I created a simple vue component and under created() I have the following function:

```
    updateChat() {
        axios.get('/api/user-info')
            .then((resp) => {
                const user = resp.data

        window.fcSettings = {
                token: "737838-363673273278-782828",
                host: "https://wchat.freshchat.com",
                externalId: user['id'],
                firstName: user['name'],
                lastName: user['surname'],
                email: user['email'],
              };

            })
            .catch((err) => {alert(err); console.log(err);})
    },
```

I'm not sure however on how to load `https://wchat.freshchat.com/js/widget.js` after this function run. I tried to ad it as a normal  tag under my bundle.js  tag but it didn't work. How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A really bad way to do it is to load it async as text and use `eval()`... But hey why do you load it before, wrap it into a function and call it later on?

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html file, add the code below to the  section

```
<script src="https://wchat.freshchat.com/js/widget.js"></script>
```

Then in your main.js file, add code below:

```
mounted() {
    axios.get('/api/user-info')
            .then((resp) => {
                const user = resp.data

        window.fcWidget.init({
                token: "737838-363673273278-782828",
                host: "https://wchat.freshchat.com",
                externalId: user['id'],
                firstName: user['name'],
                lastName: user['surname'],
                email: user['email'],
              });

            })
            .catch((err) => {alert(err); console.log(err);})
    }
  }
});
```